# How to run/re-run subset of jobs AWS Glue workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am building an AWS Glue workflow composed of long-running jobs many of which are subject to failure. Is there any way I can re-run a specific branch in my workflow after a failure?

For example, my workflow looks something like this:

```
<Start Trigger> -> [Job 1] -> [Job 2] -> [Job 4]
       ↳ [Job 4]
```

Let's say `[Job 1]` and `[Job 4]` each take 3 hours and both complete successfully. Then `[Job 2]` is triggered but fails, leaving my workflow in this state:

```
<Start Trigger> -> [Job 1 ✔] -> [Job 2 ✗] -> [Job 4]
       ↳ [Job 4 ✔]
```

I make a change which fixes `[Job 2]` and believe it will run successfully when re-run. I'd like to be able to re-run only the `[Job 2] -> [Job 4]` branch of the workflow since all other parent jobs have completed successfully.

Is there anyway this can be done in AWS Glue? I'm considering trying to build an [AWS Step Functions workflow of glue jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-amazon-redshift-based-etl-workflows-with-aws-step-functions-and-aws-glue/) as [Step Functions workflows seem to have this functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-nested-workflows.html).

Comment: This is a very important aspect of Glue Workflow development. I'm very surprised to see that there are no comments and no potential solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do this is now available since August 2020.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/resuming-workflow.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Normally i would agree. But in this instance - I disagree.  Pointing to the definitive source for the procedure is better than re-producing it here in case AWS make changes to the process and it would leave this answer out of date.  I put that answer here to make clear the feature exists now for future reference.